# Getting error "E01020031091 Failed in GetNextTool() - - Invalid operation - Major-Index: Out of range." on Okuma machine

Tags: api, runtime-error, okuma

I am running this on an Okuma control but on the second line of the following code, I get the error:

```
Dim MagPos As New DataAPI.CATC
localstring = MagPos.GetNextTool
```

THINC API is installed for sure because some other API functions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have an older version of the machine API because that error happens when a function is not supported.

> Major-Index: Out of range

Check with Okuma and see what the latest version is and they'll have to give you the install to update it.